# OpenCL for MAC using ATI card

Tags: macos, stream, opencl, ati

Hello all I would like to know whether openCL can be installed on a MAC running OSX with an ATI Raedon HD card. Also if it can Im not able to find any links where I can download the ATI Stream drivers for OSX.

Comment: is this some unusual configuration, or just a standard mac?  osx since 10.6 has all you need for normal macs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple provides the OpenCL implementation for Mac OS. As far as I know its already installed ("out of the box") in lion. I am not sure about leopard however. If you manage to upgrade the graphics drivers for your radeon you should also get CL for the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

ATI cards are poorly supported for OpenCL on 10.6 (for example there is no image support). I recommend using 10.7 if you're interested in using OpenCL with ATI cards.